# what is exactly meaning the formula n/2^h+1 in heap?

Tags: algorithm

Formula wrote in the site is :
[image]

And you can find it here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-of-building-a-heap/

But I don't understand when your input is for example 7 (give n =  7) and hight of your heap is equal 2 the result is 7/8 !!!! and before the explained result show the number of nodes !?
I can't understand what is meaning ?! can you explain to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **binary heap** has at most `ceil(n / (2 ^ (h + 1) ) )` nodes at height `h`. Following is an example of a binary tree with `height 4` [image]

Size `n = 32`, since there are 32 nodes in total.

Coming to your question, let us count the maximum number of nodes at height `h = 0` using the formula

=> `ceil(n / ( (2 ^ (h + 1) ) )`

= `ceil(32 / (2 ^ (0 + 1) ) )`

= `ceil(32 / 2)`

= `16`

Also, it is evident from the tree, there are 16 nodes in total at height `h = 0`, which confirms our idea.

Plugging in `h = 1`, `h = 2`, `h = 3`, and `h = 4` give `8`, `4`, `2`, and `1` respectively, which is again consistent with our binary tree.

Answer (score 3):

Height of a node in a heap is **its distance from leaf Node**.And height of heap is the height of root node. So as per your question when you have a heap with size 7 then it is basically a complete binary tree with height 2 as shown in example below.

[image: Binary Tree with height 2]

As per the formula max no of node at height `h` in a heap with `n` node is `ceil(n/2^h+1)`. Now as per your input. n=7 and h=2 which means max no of node at height 2 in  heap of 7 node .If you put the values you will get the result as 1, which can be seen in the pic above.

```
max node at height of 2= ceil(7/8)=1.
```

Answer (score 0):

The part that you circled and wrote What is the same as the ceil() function, which returns the smallest integer value that is bigger than or equal to a number. So, 7/8 would return as 2, which is the correct answer.